# How to find Java log file

Tags: java, openjdk, javascript

I have installed open jdk 7 in ubuntu & I have enable java logg option in java console. But I cant find the java log file as I tried my best.I have no idea what is the actual name of this log file so Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the log file location. By default, it's in;

```
 /home/<user_name>/.config/icedtea-web/log
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in this directory:

```
~/.java/deployment/log
```

[source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/tracing_logging.html#other)

Comment: It doesn't there . Now I install new oracle java . "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html#BJFGGEFG" with this document precess. Now where to find java log